# ArgoCD + Image Updater: how to update images when tracking a specific revision instead of branch

Tags: argocd

I use Argo CD with argocd-image-updater.

I want to achieve a fairly simple setup:

- my `dev` environment follows the latest helm chart in branch `main`
- my `staging` environment is locked to a specific revision of branch `main` so I can decide what version of a helm chart I want to use
- when there is a new docker image with image with `:dev` or `:stg` tag, the image is updated on respective environment.

The ApplicationSet:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  goTemplate: true
  generators:
    - matrix:
        generators:
          # generate application for each config file in subdirectories
          - git:
              repoURL: https://github.com/my-company/my-app-cluster
              revision: main
              files:
                - path: 'cluster/common/apps/my-app/config.yaml'
          - list:
              elements:
                - project: my-app-dev
                  stage: dev
                  destinationNamespace: my-app-dev
                  targetRevision: main # <-------------------------works perfectly fine
                  imageName: ghcr.io/my-company/my-app-frontend:dev
                  allowImageTags: 'regexp:\bdev\b'
                  updateStrategy: digest
                - project: my-app-stg
                  stage: stg
                  destinationNamespace: my-app-stg
                  targetRevision: my-app-0.1.5 # <-----------------troublemaker
                  imageName: ghcr.io/my-company/my-app-frontend:stg
                  allowImageTags: 'regexp:\bstg\b'
                  updateStrategy: digest
  template:
    metadata:
      name: '{{ .path.basename }}-{{ .stage }}'
      annotations:
        argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-list: 'app={{ .imageName }}'
        argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/app.allow-tags: '{{ .allowImageTags }}'
        argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/app.update-strategy: '{{ .updateStrategy }}'
        argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/write-back-method: 'git:secret:argocd/gitops-imageupdater-credentials-git'
        argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/app.pull-secret: 'secret:argocd/gitops-imageupdater-credentials-image-repository#credentials'
        # argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/git-branch: 'main:argocd/image-updater-{{.SHA256}}' # <---- can't make it work in any combination
    spec:
      project: '{{ .project }}'
      source:
        repoURL: https://github.com/my-company/my-app-manifests
        targetRevision: '{{ .targetRevision }}'
        path: '{{ .pathInRepository }}'
        helm:
          ignoreMissingValueFiles: true
          valueFiles:
            - values.yaml
            - 'values-{{ .stage }}.yaml'
      destination:
        name: in-cluster
        namespace: '{{ .destinationNamespace }}'
```

With FluxCD it's easily achievable, because it updates the HelmRelease (Application equivalent) that is in the gitops repo.
But argocd-image-updater **updates the helm repo**, so when I lock it to specific revision it simply doesn't work.

As fair I understand [docs](https://argocd-image-updater.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics/update-methods/#specifying-a-branch-to-commit-to), I should solve this by dynamically create branches.

However, the `argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/git-branch: main:image-updater-{{.SHA256}}` variable doesn't work for me (simply no value in SHA256 placeholder), the templating example `argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/git-branch: main:image-updater-{{range .Images}}-{{.Name}}-{{.NewTag}}{{end}}`also give no value. The branch ends up with a name of `image-updater-` in both cases.

When I use static branch name it leads to

> Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is
> behind\nhint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes.

error.

Can anybody please tell me how to configure it correctly? I am not sure I get the ArgoCD approach on this correctly, I am still not sure how to configure `git-branch` value, and also how to configure the `targetRevision` accordingly.

Also, if you know the better approach for this problem, please share it.